# Identify a fanfic in which Dumbledore hands Harry over to Lucius

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Dumbledore and Molly are fed up of Harry's antics after the battle at the Ministry and hand him over to Lucius for Voldemort to kill him.

The dark side finds out that Harry is actually Snape's son and decides to mentor him.

The Order of the Phoenix then rescue Harry from Malfoy Manor, only for him to find a way back to them.

Comment: Just to clarify, they hand him over later, during his time at Hogwarts, not when he's a child?

Comment: Yes. After the battle at the ministry.

Comment: Suggested keywords: "fanfiction dark harry potter". People like to collect similar fanfictions into "groups" and there are several groups, on fanfiction.net and archiveofourown.org and other websites, called "dark harry potter" and which collect fanfictions with the common element of harry potter becoming a dark wizard.